# SQL Select Statement Powershell 2.0 Print Table

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am trying to print a table of people in my database using powershell. I'd like the select statment to return results as XML, and print it to the screen for now. ATM I am having problems printing to the screen.

`$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection`

```
$conn.ConnectionString = "Server=SQLSERVER;Database=myDatabase;user id=usr;password=pss;"
$conn.Open()

$cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 100 * FROM people"

$cmd.connection = $conn
$reader = $cmd.ExecuteXmlReader()

write-output $reader
$conn.close()
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having right now? Describe what you are getting (including any error messages) and what you're expecting.

Comment: When using `ExecuteXmlReader()`, you must instruct SQL Server to return your data as XML with [`FOR XML`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx) in the query itself

Comment: adding FOR XML AUTO  fixed the error i was getting... but i'm still not able to output the XML to the screen or a file

Comment: Once again, post what you *are* getting, including any error messages, and update your post to show your current code.